# I have LIST of String Array and I need it sorted based on a date in each String Array

Tags: c#

```
    List<string[]> customerRental = new List<string[]>();
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"transactions.txt");

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(allCustomers[i]))
                    {
                        customerRental.Add(line.Split('#'));
                    }
                }
                file.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                //Catch exception
            }
```

this is the list and in each string[] I have a date at index 3. I want to sort this List based on this date.

Comment: `var result = customerRental.Orderby(x => DateTime.Parse(x[3]));`?

Comment: Sounds like that string array should *really* be an object.

Comment: Please show an example of the input and output you desire.

Comment: @David Actually I am reading a text file that is # delimeted and then spliting it into an array and sorting the contents. Is that the right approach or not?

Comment: @KfirGuy see the comment above.

Comment: How do you read the file? Post your code please so we can help you.

Comment: @Faisal: If you're performing just about any logic on this data (such as parsing one of the string values to a date for sorting) then converting it to an object is probably a good idea.  Arrays are not very good objects.  See the refactoring pattern "Replace Array With Object": https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceArrayWithObject.html

Comment: @KfirGuy code posted.

Comment: @David thank you for helping out.

Comment: @Faisal So did you try what was proposed in the first comment?

Comment: Can you post an example of the text file too?

Comment: @KfirGuy below is an example.                                                                           id#name#faisal@gmail.com#12/12/2010#amount#sender@gmail.com

Comment: @CNuts I tried that its gives error that generic.list doesnot contain definition for OrderBy even though I have imported the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example in the comments your date format is dd/MM/yyyy unless it's the month first then the day. So to sort that list you could do this

```
customerRental = customerRental.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x[3], "dd/MM/yyyy", null)).ToList();
```

If it's the month first change `dd/MM/yyyy` for `MM/dd/yyyy`

Dont forget to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: @Faisal If my answer solved your problem feel free to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to show that you've found a solution.

Comment: sorry I'm new to SO. I will after I find how to do it :)